# mapping a clojure map

Tags: collections, dictionary, clojure

I've been experimenting with the `map` function in Clojure and was wondering, what is the best practice of applying `map` to a `map` collection so that:

```
(map #(pprint (str %1 " " %2)) {:hello 1 :world 2})
```

outputs (the order doesn't really matter now):

```
:hello 1
:world 2
```

My fist idea was:

```
(def my-map {:hello 1 :world 2})
(map #(pprint (str %1 " " %2)) (keys my-map) (vals my-map))
```

But! I haven't found any evidence in documentation that Clojure (or e.g. ClojureScript) guaranties that the order of `keys` and `vals` sequences is mutually preserved.

Another idea was:

```
(map #(pprint (str (first %1) " " (rest %1))) my-map)
```

Which is not that nice as it would be with plain `%1` and `%2`.

I believe that there a better way to do this. Can you please share, if you know it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keys` and `vals` do give the same order.

Alternatively, you could map a function across the entries of the map:

```
(map (fn [[k v]] ...) {:foo 1 :bar 2})
```

Or use `reduce-kv`:

```
(reduce-kv (fn [_ k v] ...) nil {:foo 1 :bar 2})
```

Comment: Michal, can you please tell how is the nested arguments (in this case `[[k v]]`) technique called and are there any docs about it?

Comment: It's called [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)). As the function is mapped over each hash-map pair, the key and value are bound to `k` and `v`. You can see another example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`map` is for applying a function lazily over collections to produce a new collection. I'd use it when you actually need the resulting collection.

But in this case you're just enumerating k/v pairs for the side-effect of `pprint`ing them, so consider using [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) instead:

```
(doseq [[k v] {:hello 1 :world 2}]
  (pprint (str k " " v)))
```

Comment: Thank you for a good example, @danneu,  I've just learned something new :)